# How to skip keys in map function on map in scala

Tags: scala

Given a map of `Map[String, String]`.

I want to know how to skip a key from map

```
    val m =  Map("1"-> "1", "2"-> "2")
    m.map[(String, String), Map[String, String]].map{
      case(k,v)=>
        if (v == "1") {
          // Q1: how to skip this key
          // Do not need to return anything
        } else {
          // If the value is value that I want, apply some other transformation on it
          (k, someOtherTransformation(v))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a `fold`/`reduction` instead of a `map` if you want the resulting iterable to be a different size than the original.

Comment: This is not a list? It is a map? Maybe I am misunderstanding you

Comment: I corrected my comment.

Answer (score 8):

`.collect` is doing exactly what you want, it takes **partial** function, if function is not defined for some element (pair for `Map`), that element is dropped:

```
Map("1"-> "1", "2"-> "2").collect { case (k, v) if v != "1" => (k, v * 2) }
//> scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(2 -> 22)
```

Here partial function is defined for `v != "1"` (because of guard), hence element with `v == "1"` is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a "guard" on your `case` clause ...

```
case (k,v) if v != "1" => // apply some transformation on it
case (k,v) => (k,v) // leave as is
```

... or simply leave the elements you're not interested in unchanged.

```
case (k,v) => if (v == "1") (k,v) else // apply some transformation on it
```

The output of `map` is a new collection the same size as the input collection with all/some/none of the elements modified.

Comment: How about using reduce/fold as another commenter suggested? Would that be a better general practice?

Comment: @samol If Scala has the ability to discard an element, use that instead. Not all languages have that ability for their standard map function.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. As a general rule, `map` is for when you want to touch every element in a collection, `collect` is like `map` but will touch/modify selected elements. If you need a new/modified collection then `map`, `flatMap`, or `collect` would be the tools to start with. If, on the other hand, you want a single piece of data/information calculated from a collection then something from the `fold`/`reduce` family would be the ticket. Different tools for different tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Victor Moroz's answer is good for this case, but for cases where you can't make the decision on whether to skip immediately in the pattern match, use `flatMap`:

```
Map("1"-> "1", "2"-> "2").flatMap {
  case (k,v) =>
    val v1 = someComplexCalculation(k, v)
    if (v1 < 0) {
      None
    } else {
      // If the value is value that I want, apply some other transformation on it
      Some((k, someOtherTransformation(v1)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not `.filterNot` to remove all unwanted values(according to your condition) and then a `.map`?

Sample code:

```
Map("1"-> "1", "2" -> "2").filterNot(_._2 == "1").map(someFunction)
//someFunction -> whatever you would implement
```